# How to make Android app eligible to use VPN Service and publish to Google Play Console?

Tags: android, google-play-console, openvpn, android-vpn-service

I have a voip app and it is almost complete, I added VPN service to current app because it was a requirement to secure the audio phone calls, and whenever app launches it should connect to vpn first than move to the landing page of the app and user can also cancel this and move forward with authentication.

The Problem i am facing is Google Play is constantly rejecting the app going into production and says i am violating the policy.

e.g

> VpnService policy: Use of VpnService is not a permitted use case

[image]

I tried lot of things, I also tried to fill out app content safety form for vpn use and selected that vpn is core functionality as it runs first, get connected and than lands for other features like phone calls, and also mentioned them that this is carrier and telephony app which is mentioned in their guideline for an exception.

I also added prominent disclosure to use of VPN but google still does not allow to publish.
Now i want to know how i should overcome this issue , removing vpn from app is not the solution and all other vpn apps on play store how they have approved themselves.

any help in this regard will be appreciated